# Make array of flattened out value from nested array object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following array object.

```
    let reports = [
        {
            cc: 'BEL',
            cn: 'Belgium',
            entities: [
                {
                    entityName: 'Company A',
                    address: 'some address'
                }, 
                {
                    entityName: 'Company B',
                    address: 'some address'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            cc: 'LUX',
            cn: 'Luxembourg',
            entities: [
                {
                    entityName: 'Company C',
                    address: 'some address'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

I want to go through `reports` and create a new array with only the value of `entityName` how can I accomplish this?

The new array should look like `['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C']`. How can I accomplish this?

I tried doing: `reports.map(e => e.entities.map(r => r.entityName))`. However this returns:

`[['Company A', 'Company B'], ['Company C']]`

Comment: flat your result

Comment: Is `reports.map(e => e.entities.map(r => r.entityName)).flat()` only way to do it? Isn't there some other array function that can do it?

Comment: There a lot of ways but this seems to be the easiest

Comment: `.flat()` like somewhere like an extra unnecessary step. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.flat()` on your result.

```js
let reports = [
        {
            cc: 'BEL',
            cn: 'Belgium',
            entities: [
                {
                    entityName: 'Company A',
                    address: 'some address'
                }, 
                {
                    entityName: 'Company B',
                    address: 'some address'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            cc: 'LUX',
            cn: 'Luxembourg',
            entities: [
                {
                    entityName: 'Company C',
                    address: 'some address'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];




const res = reports.map(e => e.entities.map(r => r.entityName)).flat();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this where I first map entities, then flat them and finally return entityNames as a single array result:

```js
let reports = [{
    cc: 'BEL',
    cn: 'Belgium',
    entities: [{
        entityName: 'Company A',
        address: 'some address'
      },
      {
        entityName: 'Company B',
        address: 'some address'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    cc: 'LUX',
    cn: 'Luxembourg',
    entities: [{
      entityName: 'Company C',
      address: 'some address'
    }]
  }
];

const flattenedEntities = reports
  .map(({entities}) => entities)
  .flat()
  .map(({entityName}) => entityName);

console.log(flattenedEntities);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get simply by using `for` loop.

```js
var reports = [
    {
        cc: 'BEL',
        cn: 'Belgium',
        entities: [
            {
                entityName: 'Company A',
                address: 'some address'
            },
            {
                entityName: 'Company B',
                address: 'some address'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        cc: 'LUX',
        cn: 'Luxembourg',
        entities: [
            {
                entityName: 'Company C',
                address: 'some address'
            }
        ]
    }
];
var yourarray = [];
for (var j = 0; j < reports.length; j++) {
    var reportentity = reports[j].entities;
    for (var i = 0; i < reportentity.length; i++) {
        yourarray.push(reportentity[i].entityName);
    }
}

console.log(yourarray)
```